# SPO 2013 redirect using url parameter doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint-online, url, query, parameter

Using same solution proposed here:
[Confirmation Page / Custom List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/103562/confirmation-page-custom-list)

Url is included in a function that generates newpost.aspx in a pop up. It worked once but then stopped which is weird.

```
function showPopup() { var options = { 
url: 'https://xxxxx/Lists/Posts/NewPost.aspx?Source=https://xxxx/thankyou.aspx',
title: 'Submit A Recipe', 
allowMaximize: true, 
showClose: true, 
width: 625, 
height: 850
}; 
SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options); };
```

Called with:

```
<a href="javascript:showPopup()" class="btn btn-success">Submit</a> </div>
```

UPDATE:
Using an inline javascript it DOES work. The difference appears to be that the function approach adds "IsDlg=1" to the url of the pop up, whereas the inline method does not:
Function: newpost.aspx?Source=redirectpage.aspx&IsDlg=1
Inline:   newpost.aspx?Source=redirectpage.aspx
I want to use the function because it fires the "dlg" box which looks better than a bland new window.

Comment: I see you are using SP.SOD.execute(), is the Scriptlink for jQuery OnDemand parameter set to true?

Comment: Ransher-I don't know - how would I find out? Clearly sp.ui.dialog.js is not loading so I guess not. 
When I use the trick outlined here it works: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53559/sp-js-are-not-registered-to-page-for-anonymous-user-in-sharepoint-2013

Comment: On the link you provided the Sharepoint:Scriptlink has a property OnDemand="false", that was what I was asking, whether it is set to true or false for you

Comment: Using Office 365 flavor of SPO 2013, can I make that change? If so, where? In Sharepoint Designer?